# Leaving my tenure-track position for industry in January 2021,

Tags: tenure-track

Things have really gone downhill in our department because of Covid-19, and I and a few other colleagues (also on the tenure track) are planning to leave at the end of this semester, for industry.

To whom should I first resign with?  The Chair of the department?

My mind is made up, so I'm seeking the least painful path forward.  I have a job offer lined up already.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd say the chair, yes.  But if you have any shred of consideration for them, tell the chair or the dean or whoever, but tell them now, immediately, rather than spending more time asking the Internet for advice on how to do it just so.  Losing faculty midyear is going to severely disrupt their plans for getting courses taught, and they'll need all the time they can get to have any hope of resolving things.

Comment: Chair. But soon after that talk to your PhD students (if any). It's really hard if they hear it from someone else.

Comment: Presumably this depends on the local legislation and organization of the university. Could you specify a country or at least a continent of the institution?

Comment: It seems it is too late given the organization of many activities (teaching, research, planning, etc.) that are related to you, except that your contract with the university will end in this December.

Comment: Check your faculty handbook and contract.

Comment: @NateEldredge - of course, given Covid and things 'going downhill', the chair and dean are likely preparing themselves mentally for something like this. It doesn't make it easier on them, but if the writing is on the wall everyone can see it.

Comment: @JonCuster: Yeah, it's quite possible they're expecting people will leave, but they need to be told *which ones*.

Comment: @NateEldredge - oh, absolutely. This is a pretty lousy time for everyone and clear timely communication will help make it be slightly less lousy.

Answer (score 0):

When I left I first informally talked to my direct line manager to whom I usually reported (which was in my case the head of the department). Then my official (and signed) letter went to human resources to formalize the termination of my contract. Then talk to your PhD students / postdocs etc .. It was a slightly different situation as I left after I already had tenure but I guess the same procedure might work best for you as well.